# Is a unit test which uses LINQ to check multiple values acceptable?

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for a library which parses colors from user input (example: the user input “#f00” gives a red color; the user input “60,100%,100%” gives a yellow color, etc.)

One of the conditions is that the method `Parse` returns `null` when there is actually nothing to parse, i.e. when the input is either an empty string or its length is inferior to four characters. Those are the two unit tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SubmitEmptyText()
{
    var actual = new ColorParser().Parse(string.Empty);
    Assert.IsNull(actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void SubmitShortText()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(new[]{"#", "#f", "#ff"}.All(c => !new ColorParser().Parse(c).HasValue));
}
```

- Is the second method doing too much?
- Am I expected to create three method? Seriously?!
- Is the usage of functional programming here justified, or should I instead stick to the most basic way to write the tests?

Comment: I guess a potential problem with this is if one of the items fail you won't easily know which one is the culprit

Comment: There has to be a better way where the test method takes a parameter and you then decorate it such that these values are fed in somehow. MbUnit had this since 2004; MsTest does have an alternative but it sucks in comparison. http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/20/row_based_testing.aspx  This question shows the alternative. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347535/how-to-rowtest-with-mstest  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-2.aspx

Comment: NUnit has [Parameterized Tests](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=values&r=2.5)

Comment: @abuzittin gillifirca, if that code compiles and works, then my mind is blown. I did not realize that one can slap attributes onto method arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is passing parameters to common test method and supplying it with informative error message.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SubmitShortText()
    {
        var colorCodes = new[] { "#", "#f", "#ff" };
        DoAssertion(colorCodes);
    }

    private void DoAssertion(string[] colorCodes)
    {
        var parser = new ColorParser();
        foreach (var code in colorCodes)
        {
            var hasValue = parser.Parse(code).HasValue;
            Assert.IsTrue(hasValue, string.Format("Failed to parse color code '{0}'.", code));
        }
    }
```

Parametrized tests are also supported in **XUnit**:

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("#")]
    [InlineData("#f")]
    [InlineData("#ff")]
    public void SubmitShortText(string code)
    {
        var parser = new ColorParser();
        var hasValue = parser.Parse(code).HasValue;
        Assert.True(hasValue, string.Format("Failed to parse color code '{0}'.", code));
    }
```

Tests will be executed one by one. Execution will be stopped on the first failed test.

Comment: +1. You do not want the growing volume of test code to over-burden your ability to maintain it. Design, build, refactor, just as if it were as important as your "money" code. Because it is.